# Asynchronous Displaying in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I don't think the following question is rarely seen. But since I don't know how to search for the right answer, so I'm still stuck on it.

I have a label in the form and I want to show something before another job is invoked:

```
private void btnLoadEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbStatus.Text = "Loading... ";
    load();
}
private void load() 
{ 
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    lbStatus.Text = "Done";
}
```

The label won't show anything before load() is complete.

Then I changed my program usnig async/await:

```
private async void btnLoadEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbStatus.Text = "Loading... ";
    await load();
}

private async Task load()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    lbStatus.Text = "Done";
}
```

It doesn't change anything. Does anyone have any idea?

2014/4/3:

As a note, I think I've figured out how async/await works. And to avoid misleading any possible reader, I list my final solution as follows:

```
private async void btnLoadEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbStatus.Text = "Loading... ";
    string content = await loadAsync();
}
private async Task<string> loadAsync() 
{ 
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        string json = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(
                "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Taipei,tw");
        lbStatus.Text = "Done";
        return json;
    }
}
```

In practice, to meet the Decoupling Principle, "lbStatus.Text = ... " could be better moved from loadAsync() to btnLoadEvent_Click() although it works fine.

And thanks everyone who helped.

Comment: There isn't any actual background thread in all this, that `Sleep` looks like it'll run on the UI thread, which means the `"Loading..."` paint message may not get processed before the sleep. You don't get multi-threading just because of the `async await` keywords.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Thanks! But my question is how I can show the message before load() is invoked?

Comment: Marking method `async` doesn't make it asynchronous. You need a `await` call to make it asynchronously wait. your `load` method isn't asynchronous. In fact you'll get a compiler warning. My suggestion is you need a good tutorial for `async/await` [perhaps this one](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Comment: IMO, calling `Application.DoEvents` means you've gone wrong.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Thanks! That tutorial is quite helpful.

Comment: @Johnny: Don't ignore the compiler warnings. With the code in your question, the compiler will tell you what's wrong, how it will behave unexpectedly (synchronously), and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't really go async. Thread.Sleep is blocking and because your async function never yields it will still block the call site. Use `await Task.Delay(...` instead.

```
private void btnLoadEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbStatus.Text = "Loading... ";
    load();
}

private async Task load()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    lbStatus.Text = "Done";
}
```

Comment: Thank! I think my problem is solved, in a way I don't quite understand yet. I don't mean to run Sleep(5000) in my project, as you may know. However, I simply add "await Task.Delay(50);" in load() and lbStatus now shows "Loading..." before load() is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) . Set your label.Text to Loading before executing the BackgroundWorker's `RunWorkerAsync` method. Do your stuff (like your Thread.Sleep(5000)) in the `Do_Work` event and change the status of your label in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event. Visit [this link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) to see an example.

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` is no good than `async/await` when used properly.

Comment: Isn't it a lot easier to do such things with a backgroundworker?

Comment: @user3441808: No, it isn't.

Comment: I don't think so, In what way you think `BackgroundWorker` is easy to work with? `BackgroundWorker` shouldn't be used anymore in new projects, it is a legacy component.

Comment: Ok you guys are probably right. But as it is a Winforms (that's legacy) application, why not? Anyway, thanks for letting me know. I just gave it a try ;)

Comment: @J.L: Thanks for the answer. I've tried several ways before posting this question. And I agree with Sriram that async/await is much more easier than BackgroundWorker. I don't really mean to run sleep(5000) in my project, you know, it's merely for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use BackgroundWorker. Something like that.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    label1.Text = "Loading";
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    load();
}

private void load()
{
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
   if(InvokeRequired)
      this.Invoke(new Action(()=>label1.Text = "Done"));
}
```